# Do I have to fix shift/reduce problems in Yacc manually?

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

I am having the hardest time trying to remove two shift/reduce problems in my grammar. I cant find a solution anywhere. I see that Yacc apparently will prefer the shift, but if so then why won't mine compile? I know one of the issues is the dangling if-else, but the other, I have no idea. I would prefer that Yacc just handle it for me. The error message says `2 shift reduce conflicts`

````
void yyerror (char *s);
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int yylex();
extern int yytext[];
extern FILE *yyin;
%}
%start program
%token LTE GTE BEQUALS NOTEQUALS BEGCOMMENT ENDCOMMENT COMMENT GREATER LESS COMMA PLUS SUB MULT DIV EQUAL LP RP LB RB LC RC SEMICOLON INT FLOAT VOID IF WHILE RETURN  ID NUM 
%nonassoc IFX

%nonassoc ELSE
%%
program : declaration_list { printf("\nACCEPT\n"); };

declaration_list : declaration_list declaration     
                 | declaration          
                 ;

declaration  : var_declaration 
         | fun_declaration
             ;

var_declaration : type_specifier ID SEMICOLON   
                | type_specifier ID LB NUM RB SEMICOLON 
                ;

type_specifier : INT      
               | VOID   
           ;

fun_declaration : type_specifier ID LP params RP compound_stmt  ;

params : param_list | VOID ;

param_list : param_list COMMA param 
           | param                  
             ;

param : type_specifier ID           
      | type_specifier ID LB RB   
      ;


compound_stmt : LC local_declarations statement_list RC  
              ;

local_declarations : local_declarations var_declaration 
                   | /* empty */ ;

statement_list : statement_list statement
               | /* empty */ ;

statement : expression_stmt
          | compound_stmt
          | selection_stmt
          | iteration_stmt
          | return_stmt ;

expression_stmt : expression SEMICOLON
                | SEMICOLON 
        ;

selection_stmt : ifsubroutine  statement        
               | ifsubroutine  statement ELSE     
               ;

ifsubroutine : IF  LP expression RP  
        ;

iteration_stmt : whilesubroutine LP expression RP statement          
                ;
whilesubroutine : WHILE   ;

return_stmt : RETURN SEMICOLON              

            | RETURN expression SEMICOLON  
            ;

expression : var EQUAL expression     
           | simple_expression      
           ;

var : ID                    
    | ID LB expression RB 
    ;

simple_expression : additive_expression relop additive_expression  
                  | additive_expression                            
                  ;

relop : LTE | LESS | GREATER | GTE | EQUAL| NOTEQUALS ;

additive_expression : additive_expression addop term    
                    | term                              
                    ;

addop : PLUS 
      | SUB 
      ;

term : term mulop factor    
     | factor               
     ;

mulop : MULT 
      | DIV 
      ;

factor : LP expression RP 
       | var                
       | call               
       | NUM                
       ;

call : ID LP args RP  
     ;

args : arg_list | /* empty */ ;

arg_list : arg_list COMMA expression 
         | expression              
         ;

%%
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   if (!yyin)
   {
      printf("no file\n");
      exit(0);
   }
   yyparse();
}
void yyerror(char *s)
{
   printf("\nREJECT\n");
//   printf("error from yyerror\n");
   exit(0);
}
int yywrap()
{
  // printf("in yywarp\n");
   exit(0);
}```
````

Comment: If your code doesn't compile, it has nothing to do with parse conflicts. But unless you show the code and the compile errors, nobody can give you a better hint than "read the error message".

Comment: @rici i just edited it and added my .y file but I dont get what else could be wrong besides that

Comment: **and the compiler errors** (which conveniently usually contain line numbers telling you where to look.)

Comment: i did. its the just the one. "wrning: 2 shit/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-sr]"

Comment: Then what do you mean by "won't compile"? That's just a warning and will not stop you from compiling.

Comment: @rici oh, my mistake. I guess, the issue is that it seems to not finish or something. I never get an "accept" or "reject" message, but if i remove the errors completely by removing some rules then i will get the appropriate message

Comment: You need to provide more accurate and more complete problem descriptions. Otherwise, you're relying on telepathy or clairvoyance, neither of which are particularly reliable debugging tools.

Comment: Oh I didn’t know that. How do I tell it that it’s the end of file

Comment: I do think you are correct about the end of file. If I put errors in the middle of my text input then I get “reject” but if it’s accept, it never returns anything

Comment: I think it is terminating. You get a shell prompt, right? But only you know for sure because you are in front of your machine and I'm on a different continent where I can't see over your shoulder. I did my best in my answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `yywrap()` implementation calls `exit()`. That means that as soon as end-of-file is seen by the scanner, the application will terminate. So the parser will not be able to finish its work.

In general, you should use `%option noyywrap` in your (f)lex file, to avoid the need for providing `yywrap`. Or use the default implementation in `-lfl`. But if you insist on implementing it, it should return 1 to indicate that there is nothing more to read.

Also, `extern int yytext[];` is unnecessary, because you don't refer to `yytext` anywhere in your parser. And you should not refer to `yytext` in your parser; such usage is almost always an error. But if you did use `yytext`, the declaration would be wrong: it's a *pointer* (not an array) to `char` (not `int`). Your C compiler probably won't flag that error.

Comment: I once had the yynowrap in there but i had a compile error so i took it out. Ive never used Yacc so I didnt even know what it was for. Ill try to put it back.

Comment: @codyp: yywrap has nothing to do with bison. It's used (or not) by the lexical scanner generated by (f)lex. And please don't say "compile error" unless you are actually referring to an error message produced by a *compiler*. Otherwise you just confuse people. Flex and bison are code generators. Gcc is a compiler.